# How to set space of sw_rear and right Edge SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Clink to see image [MY sw_rear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClFDY.png)

When running

Clink to see image [Space is 1/3 of display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QiQj.png)

but i want set space is 5/6 of display

Comment: are you want to increase the width or decrase the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the width like use property of `rearViewRevealWidth` in `SWL`

> // so the revealed frontView width is kept constant when bounds change as opposed to the rear or right width.
>
> @property (nonatomic) CGFloat rearViewRevealWidth;

**Objective-C**

```
revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-100.0f; //customize the width/space
```

**Swift**

```
revealViewController!.rearViewRevealWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-100 //customize the width/space
```

Comment: how to set all size display 4", 4.7" or more

Comment: @TeezanateepWongprapai -- welcome my brother , how much width do u need to display the rear width

Comment: @TeezanateepWongprapai -- chek the updated answer , customize the width (100 add your width), its working as if you are in iphone 4 then width as (320-100) so your final rearwidth as 220, it is work for all devices and future device also

Comment: i want spece = width of menu item

Comment: 5-6 means tell the point bro , it is easy to optimize and check the updated answer,

Comment: @TeezanateepWongprapai its is float /CGFloat bro, for information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190807/why-are-uiview-frames-made-up-of-floats

Comment: @TeezanateepWongprapai -- tanx a lot my brother

Answer (score 0):

The width is controlled by the `rearViewRevealWidth` on your `SWRevealViewController`.

For example:

```
revealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: myRearViewController, 
                                              frontViewController: myFrontViewController)
revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth = myWidth
```

where the width is a `CGFloat`.

From the documentation for the rearViewRevealWidth property:

> Defines how much of the rear or right view is shown, default is 260. Negative values indicate that the reveal width should be computed by substracting the full front view width, so the revealed frontView width is kept constant when bounds change as opposed to the rear or right width.

Comment: I dont understand, I set it like so: revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width-100 which is the same as if I do the following: revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 145 nothing is different!?